Sub panel location question
Can a sub panel be installed below the main panel, as shown in this picture? My panel is between a window and a wall, with no room on the sides....Thank you.

best to go and ask for permit

Electrical code often dictates the amount of clearance around a panel or sub-panel, and also dictates heights above the floor.  So first you'd need to check your local electrical code to see what is allowed for a panel location.
But my guess is that you'll find (if you open up the wall below the existing panel) that there are cables running out of the bottom of the panel, which might be in the way of a sub panel in that location.  You could determine that by taking the front cover off the current panel and seeing which direction(s) the wires exit from this existing panel.
Depending on the reason for a sub panel, you may end up (if this is the only location possible and you can't put another panel below, for whatever reason) needing to put in a whole replacement panel with more capacity (or at least with more breaker slots).

There is a rule for panels (whether main panel or subpanel) that they need a clearance in front of 30" wide x 36" deep. The catch here is that you have a window sticking out an inch or two into that area. And it looks like you have a door to the side that may swing into that area. Whether any of that - or any other conditions not visible in the picture - cause any code concerns is unknown. Some inspectors will be much pickier than others about this rule (as with many rules).
The existing panel would be grandfathered in, assuming it was permitted/inspected when installed. But a new panel in the same basic location (e.g., below it) might not be allowed, depending on window, door and other issues.
